# Procurar uma palavra em um resultado JSON

Tags: php, json

Pessoal tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
"results": {
"collection1": [
  {
    "prod": {
      "text": "COLCHÃO NAUTIKA KING SIZE"
```

Tenho um formulário de busca:

```
<form id="search" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="search" />
          <input type="submit" value="buscar">
          </form>
```

E para mostrar o resultado fiz o seguinte:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];    
foreach($results['results']['collection1'] as $collection) {

                if(strpos($collection['prod']['text'],$search) !== false) {
                echo $collection['prod']['text'] . "'><br />";  }
```

Acontece 1 problema:

- A busca só da certo quando colocamos em letra MAIÚSCULA, pois o resultado do jSON está em maiúsculo.

Answer (score 3):

Altere o código do `if`, ao invés de usar `==` use a função [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php).

```
if(strpos($collection['prod']['text'], "COLCHÃO")) !== false)
```

`strpos` procura pelo primeiro índice de uma string, se não achar retorna false.

Comment: bacana! Só ajeitando um erro: if(strpos($collection['prod']['text'], "COLCHÃO") !== false)

Comment: Tinha feito certo depois editei e coloquei um a mais. Faltou dar erro de compilação!